# User input in exponential function in Python3 returns nothing

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input

I am just starting out with python3, and I'm trying to write a simple exponential function. Now, what I've written below does work, however, I want to change the code in such a way, that it would allow for user input and then give out the answer based on that input.

```
def raise_to_power(base_num, pow_num):
    result = 1
    for index in range(pow_num):
        result = result*base_num
    return result print(raise_to_power(2, 3))
print(raise_to_power(2, 3))
```

This is what my attempt at getting the new code to work looks like.

```
base_num = float(input("Enter base number: "))
pow_num = float(input("Enter power number"))
def raise_to_power(base_num, pow_num):
    result = 1
    for index in range(pow_num):
        result = result*base_num
    return result
print(raise_to_power)
```

However, I consistently get the following message as a result instead of an answer

> <function raise_to_power at 0x7f8fe15baf70>

What do I do about this?

Comment: You're not calling the function. The `()` are missing. Should be `print(raise_to_power(base_num, pow_num))`

Comment: `print(raise_to_power(base_num, pow_num))`

Comment: Here: `print(raise_to_power)` _what_ are you raising to _which_ power?

Comment: you are missing your arguments to the function

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for your responses! So, when I try to do what you have suggested, with print(raise_to_power(base_num, pow_num)), I get an error message of > 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: You have a `range` function in your `raise_to_power`. Range only accepts integer inputs, so you getting this error means that you are trying to put non-integer values in for `pow_num`.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(raise_to_power(base_num, pow_num))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I did try doing that, and it ended up giving another error - >'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: @user3697625, it's not possible to do a loop in range of a Float number.

Comment: @user3697625 Sorry, I think I had edited the comment to show the error as you were typing out your comment! It gives a TypeError of > 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: you can only do a for loop for integer values.

Comment: @mightyandweakcoder, thank you! This has helped, as soon as I changed it to "int", it worked like a charm, thank you! This is something I will need to understand better and keep in mind for the future.